# is it safe to throw an exception or call QueueUserAPC again inside an APC routine?

Tags: c++, c, winapi

I'm using a waitable timer created by `CreateWaitableTimerW` and integrating it into io completetion port through APC routines by calling `GetQueuedCompletionStatusEx` and setting `fAlertable` to `true`.

in my tests and codes this seems to work very well even if I throw an exception it seems to be propagated correctly. but I heard recently that I shouldn't throw exceptions from inside `c` callbacks as the stack might not unwind correctly and even if it does (like here) no destructors at the `c` code is called so resources leaks are very likely !

the documentation doesn't say anything about throwing exceptions from the routine so I don't know am I doing something wrong ? I also heard that on windows c++ exceptions are implemented using `SEH` exceptions which can be used also in `c` so it's fine to throw exceptions from `c` callbacks here ? and if the routine throws while there are other routines in the queue will they be discarded ? or stay queued ?

finally, the documentation states :

> It is possible to sleep or wait for an object within the APC. If you perform an alertable wait inside an APC, it will recursively dispatch the APCs. This can cause a stack overflow

I don't understand this well . does it mean that performing an alertable wait inside an APC causes it to be called again immediately again leading to continuous recursive call ? or will cause the rest of the routines to be called immediately from inside the current APC which may cause stack overflow at high routines ?

Comment: [Relevant](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20171012-00/?p=97215).

Comment: very useful ! this answers the first part of the question .

Comment: _does it mean that performing an alertable wait inside an APC causes it to be called again immediately again leading to continuous recursive call?_  That's not the way I read it.  I think that what they mean is that your APC (and others) are _eligible_ to be called and may therefore be called recursively.

Comment: no *immediately* of course, but only when apc will be queued to your thread.simply call stack still will be containing previous apc call data. so new apc call really will be reqursive

Comment: and when thread exit from apc call - kernel check - are another apc exist inside thread. if yes - next existing apc will be called. if you will be always and unconditionally insert apc to current thread inside apc call - you never return from apc loop. but really need look for concrete code. possible do very many things, but need deep understand what we doing

Comment: I changed the design now . the loop class now has a queue of timer pointers and the apc will insert the current timer in the queue and return so the loop will check after each apc for timers in the queue